# R Statistics: Read subset of irregular file into dataframe

Tags: r, text, subset, read.table

I have a text file that consists of 4 separate components (the source, usage, and actual data associated with a dataset).  I want to read each component into a separate R object.

An example of the file format follows.  Every file will have the keywords SOURCE, STORY, USAGE, and DATASET as delimiters.

## Example Dataset

```
SOURCE
Boxofficemojo.com

STORY
These lines, of variable length and number, would contain the story behind the dataset.

USAGE
"Course"    "Year"  "Section"   "Exercise"
"Course1"   5   9   "ex 3"
"Course1"   5   9   "ex 4"
"Course1"   5   9   "ex 5"
"Course2"   5   9   "ex 3"
"Course2"   5   9   "ex 4"

DATASET
Dataset with headers follows.
```

My problem is only in reading the USAGE section as a dataframe.  I wrote a quick line-by-line parser that scans the file for the keywords USAGE and DATASET and returns their line numbers.  However, this code works:

```
Usage <- read.table(Output.File, skip= 9, nrows = 6, header = TRUE)
```

but this code does not

```
Usage <- read.table(Output.File, skip= Beginrow, nrows = Endrow - Beginr4w, header = TRUE)
```

How can I make read.table(), or any other function, allow the use of variable skip and number of rows?  Alternatively, is there a simpler way to read in the data between USAGE and DATASET as a data table?

USAGE will always have 4 columns, with the same header names as in the file above, but the number of lines of usage can range from 1 to any arbitrary number.

Comment: In the data as you present it, you would only want `skip=7`

Comment: I pasted the code from a slightly different file.  I will be running this on many files, eventually.  The code was merely meant to show that it works when hard coded, but fails when variables are used.

Comment: Well the difference must be somewhere else - it cannot be "variables" vs "hard coded" because there is no such difference. Your second version will work if you have computed `skip` and `nrows` correctly

Comment: Maybe a typo in `Endrow - Beginr4w`  (you may have meant Beginrow instead of Beginr4w -- you said you pasted it, so I assume the typo was there in the original)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a somewhat extensible method. First, read the entire file into a variable with `readLines`. I'll use a `textConnection` for reproducibility here on SO, but you should just read from the file.

```
x <- readLines(con=textConnection('
SOURCE
Boxofficemojo.com

STORY
These lines, of variable length and number, would contain the story behind the dataset.

USAGE
"Course"    "Year"  "Section"   "Exercise"
"Course1"   5   9   "ex 3"
"Course1"   5   9   "ex 4"
"Course1"   5   9   "ex 5"
"Course2"   5   9   "ex 3"
"Course2"   5   9   "ex 4"

DATASET
Dataset with headers follows.'))
```

Filter out the preceding empty line that I introduced:

```
head(x)
# [1] ""                                                                                       
# [2] "SOURCE"                                                                                 
# [3] "Boxofficemojo.com"                                                                      
# [4] ""                                                                                       
# [5] "STORY"                                                                                  
# [6] "These lines, of variable length and number, would contain the story behind the dataset."
allcaps <- grep("^[A-Z]+$", x)
if (allcaps[1] > 1) x <- x[-(1:(allcaps[1]-1))]
```

I infer that a row with nothing but upper-case letters indicates a "header". This could also be done with `cumsum(x %in% c("USAGE",...))`:

```
str( x2 <- split(x, cumsum(grepl("^[A-Z]+$", x))) )
# List of 4
#  $ 1: chr [1:3] "SOURCE" "Boxofficemojo.com" ""
#  $ 2: chr [1:3] "STORY" "These lines, of variable length and number, would contain the story behind the dataset." ""
#  $ 3: chr [1:8] "USAGE" "\"Course\"    \"Year\"  \"Section\"   \"Exercise\"" "\"Course1\"   5   9   \"ex 3\"" "\"Course1\"   5   9   \"ex 4\"" ...
#  $ 4: chr [1:2] "DATASET" "Dataset with headers follows."
```

(You may choose to remove the trailing empty-string as well, perhaps with something like `x2 <- lapply(x2, head, n=-1)`, though the last would suffer because it doesn't have it. Using `Filter(nchar, x2)` might work as well, but it assumes that there are no "intentional" blank lines. Over to you.)

This next step is perhaps cosmetic, but makes the "header" the list element name, with the subsequent rows its data:

```
str( x3 <- setNames(lapply(x2, `[`, -1L),
                    sapply(x2, `[`, 1L)) )
# List of 4
#  $ SOURCE : chr [1:2] "Boxofficemojo.com" ""
#  $ STORY  : chr [1:2] "These lines, of variable length and number, would contain the story behind the dataset." ""
#  $ USAGE  : chr [1:7] "\"Course\"    \"Year\"  \"Section\"   \"Exercise\"" "\"Course1\"   5   9   \"ex 3\"" "\"Course1\"   5   9   \"ex 4\"" "\"Course1\"   5   9   \"ex 5\"" ...
#  $ DATASET: chr "Dataset with headers follows."
```

And finally, you can do whatever you need to the embedded elements:

```
x3$USAGE <- read.table(textConnection(x3$USAGE), header=TRUE)
str(x3)
# List of 4
#  $ SOURCE : chr [1:2] "Boxofficemojo.com" ""
#  $ STORY  : chr [1:2] "These lines, of variable length and number, would contain the story behind the dataset." ""
#  $ USAGE  :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  4 variables:
#   ..$ Course  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Course1","Course2": 1 1 1 2 2
#   ..$ Year    : int [1:5] 5 5 5 5 5
#   ..$ Section : int [1:5] 9 9 9 9 9
#   ..$ Exercise: Factor w/ 3 levels "ex 3","ex 4",..: 1 2 3 1 2
#  $ DATASET: chr "Dataset with headers follows."
```

Comment: Ok.  This works.  I hope that I get good enough at R to understand the 75% of what appears above that I don't currently get, so thank you!

Comment: How would this work if one wanted to restrict to the actual names of the labels?  That is, not look for everything in all caps, but rather for particular keywords?

Comment: `x3[ names(x3) %in% c("USAGE","DATASET") ]` would reduce it to just the two. This method is a little brute-force, meaning if your files are huge then it will suffer in efficiency. If that's the case, you would do better with something outside of R doing the filtering. Perhaps `readLines(pipe("sed -ne '/USAGE/,/DATASET/p' ProfessorE.txt"))` is a start.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that first you have to manage to select the desired part of the string that contains the relevant data for you and from that substring you read then the csv. In the solution below the `strsplit` function is used to obtain the part between USAGE and DATASE, no matter how many rows. I have basically split the string into convenient pieces. You can know more at [strsplit](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html):

```
str <- 'SOURCE
Boxofficemojo.com

STORY
These lines, of variable length and number, would contain the story behind the dataset.

USAGE
"Course"    "Year"  "Section"   "Exercise"
"Course1"   5   9   "ex 3"
"Course1"   5   9   "ex 4"
"Course1"   5   9   "ex 5"
"Course2"   5   9   "ex 3"
"Course2"   5   9   "ex 4"

DATASET
Dataset with headers follows.'

# get the desired part of the string
datasetStr <- strsplit(paste0(strsplit(str, 'USAGE')[[1]][2]), 'DATASET')[[1]][1]
# read it as data frame
df <- read.csv(text = datasetStr, sep = '\t')
```

which outputs

```
> df
  Course....Year..Section...Exercise
1             Course1   5   9   ex 3
2             Course1   5   9   ex 4
3             Course1   5   9   ex 5
4             Course2   5   9   ex 3
5             Course2   5   9   ex 4
```